# How to avoid repeated onPause() -> onResume() calls for already resumed singleTask Activity if someone tries to reopen it?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-finish

I have an android activity with "singleTask" flag in manifest. I am closing streaming operation in onPause state of activity. Problem is, onPause() -> and onResume() is called again and again when my background service tries to reopen it. Because of that my streaming is getting disconnected.

I tried to pause streaming in onStop method, but it has some side effects, like in few cases we are able to hear sound in background of streaming.

Can you please let me know is there a way to avoid onPause->onResume call if singleTask activity is already open?

Thanks

Comment: If this is the case then you can go for maintaining flag.

Comment: Why are you using `singleTask`?